# Why my WPF window did not show ToList<> property while writing MongoDB(c#) query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using Mongodb(c#) in my WPF App.
I wrote query as

```
 var server = MongoServer.Create(this.connectionString);
        var db = server.GetDatabase(DATABASE);
        var loadRiskAlertTypeSettings = db.GetCollection(RISKALERTSETTINGS_TBL);
        var qry = Query.EQ("UserName", ConsoleMain.lblUname.Content.ToString());
        List<RiskAlertTypeSettings> userResult = loadRiskAlertTypeSettings.FindAs<RiskAlertTypeSettings>(qry).ToList<RiskAlertTypeSettings>();
```

But it did not showing ToList<> property in my current working window.
I used above query in my App several times in different windows.
But in my present window it did not showing?

I traced.But i did not find any solution.

Can any one guide me in that?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and I don't see any problem for doing this:

```
var userResult = loadRiskAlertTypeSettings
    .FindAs<RiskAlertTypeSettings>(qry)
    .ToList();
```

The method ToList() is in System.Linq namespace, so check if you imports have included it.

```
using System.Linq;
```